# Не срабатывает .css, почему ? (мало кода)

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

```
if ( $("#side-2").prop("checked") ) {
        alert("Этаж 8-9. дом 1-4. правая часть");
        $("#flat-image").css("background", "url(<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/flats/floors/8-9-right-bigger.png) center no-repeat");
};
```

Натягиваю шаблон на вордпресс и нужен простенький скрипт, алерт срабатывает а стиль не меняется, почему ?

Правка: Заметил что когда использую `<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>`, то стиль вообще не применяется, а когда прописываю просто путь, то стиль применяется, но так как это Wordpress, то не срабатывает.

Comment: нет элемента с id=flat-image

Comment: @Grundy Есть, 100%

Comment: а вот и нет, выведи `$("#flat-image").length` В алерте. Ну и начинать надо всегда с просмотра ошибок в консоли

Comment: @Grundy показало "1", в консоли ошибок нет

Comment: Может не правильный путь к картинке? В инпекторе если посмотреть добавляется стиль к элементу? Если да, то проблема только в пути к файлу

Comment: скорее всего, в следующем условии этот стиль перетирается

Comment: в каком файле вы располагаете этот скрипт?

Comment: @alenkins скрипт в файле website/js/script.js страница которая вызывает скрипт website/page.php, а картинка находится по адресу website/img/flats/floors/8-9-right-bigger.png

Comment: Смотрели, что выводит `bloginfo('template_url')`? Каталог текущей темы. Папка `img` там находится?

Comment: А вообще странно ожидать, что в браузере выполнится серверный код.

Comment: @Ponio, а в браузере и не должен выполняться серверный код. Если настроить сервер так, чтобы .js-файлы обрабатывались как .php-файлы, то всё будет работать. Именно это, скорее всего, и не сделал автор вопроса.

Comment: @BimBam ну и чего вы хотели-то?) пхп-код в js-файлах не исполняется, отсюда и проблема

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала прочтите инфу о "jQuery в режиме noConflict" по ссылке [https://codex.wordpress.org/Справочник_по_функциям/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_.D0.B2_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5_noConflict](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_.D0.B2_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5_noConflict) когда прочтете поменяйте `$` на `jQuery`
2. Попробуйте использовать не `bloginfo()`, а `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Эм.. А при чём тут это?

Comment: В WordPress jQuery грузиться в noConflict режиме, в котором отсутствует  `$`. В кносоли запросы будут работать, но не факт что `$` в консоли будет равен jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Прописал вручную путь, всё сработало

```
 /wp-content/themes/lovelyhouse/img/flats/floors/8-9-right-bigger.png
```

Answer (score 0):

В functions.php вставьте:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
function my_scripts() { 
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'my_bloginfo', 
    array(
       'template_url'   => get_template_directory_uri(),
    ));
}
```

А в JS скрипте так:

```
$("#flat-image").css("background", "url(" + my_bloginfo.template_url + "/img/flats/floors/8-9-right-bigger.png) center no-repeat");
```